# Unable to write file after making exe file

Tags: python, exe, pandas.excelwriter

I have written the following python code in the jupyter notebook as:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
  
PATH="C:\\Users\\ankit19.gupta\\Desktop\\test1"
data = [['Ankit', 28], ['Akshat', 28]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
os.chdir("C://Users//ankit19.gupta//Desktop//test1")
print(os.getcwd())
PATH="C:\\Users\\ankit19.gupta\\Desktop\\test1"
xlsx_file1 = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_')) + 'Test' + '.xlsx'
out_path1 = PATH+ "/Generated_Data/"+xlsx_file1
   
print("Writing excel file") # Till now code is executed successfully
   
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path1, engine='xlsxwriter') 
   
print("Used ExcelWriter") # Don't get this print statement  

data.to_excel(writer1,index=False)
print("File is written")
writer1.save()
print("Completed")
```

I have created a pandas dataframe and store the data of this dataframe in an excel file and writing it on the disk. It executed successfully when I run it on jupyter notebook but when I convert it into an .py file using `!jupyter nbconvert --to script test1.ipynb` and get .exe file from .py file using `!pyinstaller test1.py` then when I open the .exe file from the directory `\test1\dist\test1` then console gets open and show the print statement as `Writing excel file` and then console gets closed and I don't get the statement `Used ExcelWriter` from the print() function.

I don't know why it is happening while using executable file though I have changed the current working directory. Can anyone please help me ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have it printed out any error messeges?

Comment: No. Console automatically closed without showing any error message. I have written print statements to detect which statement is not executing. Without making exe, it run successfully on jupyter notebook  @AnhPC03

Comment: Add, or modify, a print statement to print `outpath1` to ensure the file is going to where you think it is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran your code on Windows, then `os.chdir` with linux template is wrong. Otherwise, your destination directory must be existed before you write to

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
  
PATH="C:\\Users\\ankit19.gupta\\Desktop\\test1"
data = [['Ankit', 28], ['Akshat', 28]]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\ankit19.gupta\\Desktop\\test1")
print(os.getcwd())
xlsx_file1 = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_')) + 'Test' + '.xlsx'
out_path1 = PATH+ "\\Generated_Data\\"

# make sure path existed
os.makedirs(out_path1, exist_ok = True)

out_file = PATH+ "\\Generated_Data\\" + xlsx_file1
   
print("Writing excel file") # Till now code is executed successfully
   
writer1 = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file, engine='xlsxwriter') 
   
print("Used ExcelWriter") # Don't get this print statement  

data.to_excel(writer1,index=False)
print("File is written")
writer1.save()
print("Completed")
```

Comment: Path is correct.

Comment: @ankit Have you added this line `os.makedirs(out_path1, exist_ok = True)` and try again?

Comment: I have tried it but now `Writing excel file` is also not showing.

Comment: @ankit I've updated my code, check and try it again

Comment: Still getting same as I got initially. It is showing statement "Writing excel file" and then console gets closed. @AnhPC03

Comment: @ankit sorry about last update, I put my PC path. I've updated my code, check and try it again

Comment: No, I had changed that PATH according to my system otherwise I get error. Could you please tell me whether this code is working for you or not after converting it into exe and then run that exe file ?

Comment: Because your code did not check if the path existed or not, so it would throw FileNotFound exception